# Compressing an AVAsset (mainly AVMutableComposition)

Tags: ios, video, compression, avfoundation, avasset

I have a video with these specs

> - Format :    H.264 , 1280x544
> - FPS :       25
> - Data Size : 26MB
> - Duration  : 3:00
> - Data Rate : 1.17 Mbit/s

While experimenting ,I performed a `removeTimeRange(range : CMTimeRange)` on every *other* frame (*total frames = 4225*). This results in the video becoming 2x faster , so the duration becomes **1:30**.

However when I export the video, the video becomes 12x larger in size i.e. **325MB**.This makes sense since this technique is decomposing the video into about **2112** pieces and stitching it back together. Apparently, in doing so the compression among individual frames is lost, thus causing the enormous size.

This causes *stuttering* in the video when played with an `AVPlayer` and therefore poor performance.

**Question** : How can I apply some kind of compression while stitching back the frames so that the video can play smoothly and also be less in size?

I only want a point in the right direction. Thanks!

**CODE**

1) Creating an AVMutableComposition from Asset & Configuring it

```
func configureAssets(){

let options =    [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : "true"]
let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Push", withExtension: "mp4")! , options : options)

let videoAssetSourceTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first! as AVAssetTrack

let comp = AVMutableComposition()
let videoCompositionTrack = comp.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

do {

    try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration),
        of: videoAssetSourceTrack,
        at: kCMTimeZero)


    deleteSomeFrames(from: comp)

    videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoAssetSourceTrack.preferredTransform

}catch { print(error) }

asset = comp   }
```

2) Deleting every other frame.

```
   func deleteSomeFrames(from asset : AVMutableComposition){

let fps =               Int32(asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first!.nominalFrameRate)
let sumTime =           Int32(asset.duration.value)  /  asset.duration.timescale;
let totalFrames =       sumTime * fps
let totalTime =         Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
let frameDuration =     Double(totalTime / Float(totalFrames))
let frameTime =         CMTime(seconds: frameDuration, preferredTimescale: 1000)


for frame in Swift.stride(from: 0, to: totalFrames, by: 2){

    let timing =    CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(frameTime, Float64(frame))

    print("Asset Duration = \(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))")
    print("")

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: timing, duration : frameTime)
    asset.removeTimeRange(timeRange)
}

print("duration after time removed = \(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))")
}
```

3) Saving the file

```
  func createFileFromAsset(_ asset: AVAsset){

let documentsDirectory =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
let filePath =            documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-vid.mp4")

if let exportSession =    AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality){

    exportSession.outputURL = filePath
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        print("finished: \(filePath) :  \(exportSession.status.rawValue) ")

        if exportSession.status.rawValue == 4{

            print("Export failed -> Reason: \(exportSession.error!.localizedDescription))")
            print(exportSession.error!)

        }
 }}}
```

4) Finally update the ViewController to play the new Composition!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//  Create the AVPlayer and play the composition

assetConfig.configureAssets()
let snapshot : AVComposition =  assetConfig.asset  as! AVComposition
let playerItem =                AVPlayerItem(asset : snapshot)
player =                        AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
let playerLayer =               AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame =             CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width : self.view.frame.width , height : self.view.frame.height)

self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player?.play()

  }
```

Comment: Can you share your code for creating the edited video? Are you using `AVMutableComposition`?

Comment: I AM using `AVMutableComposition` . I've updated the question with some code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AVMutableComposition`,you will notice that each composition may contain one or more `AVCompositionTrack(or AVMutableCompositionTrack)`,and the best way to edit your composition was to operate each track, but not the whole composition.

but if your purpose is to faster your video's rate, editing tracks will not be necessary.

so i will try my best to tell you what i know about your question

### About video Stuttering while playing

#### Possible reason of stuttering

notice that you are using method `removeTimeRange(range: CMTimeRange)`,this method will remove the timeRange on composition yes, but will **NOT** auto fill the empty of each time range

```
Visualize Example
[F stand for Frame,E stand for Empty]

org_video    -->  F-F-F-F-F-F-F-F...
after remove time range, the composition will be like this
after_video  -->  F-E-F-E-F-E-F-E...
and you might think that the video will be like this
target_video -->  F-F-F-F...
```

this is the most possible reason about stuttering during playback.

#### Suggested solution

So if you want to shorten your video, make it rate more faster/slower,you possible need to use the method `scaleTimeRange:(CMTimeRange) toDuration:(CMTime)`

```
Example
AVMutableComposition * project;//if this video is 200s

//Scale
project.scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, project.duration) toDuration:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(100,kCMTimeMaxTimescale)
```

this method is to make the video faster/slower.

## About the file size

a video file's size might effected by **bit rate** and **format type** ,if your using H.264,the most possible reason causing size enlarge will be **bit rate**.

in your code,you are using `AVAssetExportSession`

```
AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName:     AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
```

you gave the preset which is `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`
in my own application project, after i was using this preset, the video's bit rate will be 20~30Mbps,no matter your source video's bit rate. and, well using apple's preset will not allowed you to set the bit rate manually, so.

#### Possible Solution

There is a third part tool called [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession),this session will allowed you to fully config your export session, you might want to try to study this code about custom export session's preset.

here is what i can tell you right now. wish could help :>

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I used  `removeTimeRange(..)`  deliberately since I wanted to  reduce the overall frames in the video.  Also calculating `frameTime` within the `for loop` as you would've noticed allows me to manipulate the video on a _per frame basis_  . I noticed that `scaleTimeRange(..)` doesn't actually modify the video iteslf but simply the metadata. This is seen in the video's  **Bit Rate** when the timeRange is shortened. So sadly, the video can only be shortened to 1/9th ~ **240fps**  as anything more than that is too much for the hardware.

Comment: One More thing , the problem persists even when `AVCompositionTrack ` is used instead of `AVMutableComposition` . Perhaps I am missing something because inside the `for` loop, any kind of `timeRange` modification will cause a tiny stutter / blank frame or another inconsistency in  the video.

Comment: Ehh.. well have you tried using kCMTimeMaxTimeScale during remove time range? is stutter was caused by different time scale? my application was kind of video editor, and i was setting all time scale to kCMTimeMaxTimeScale, when i playback and export my composition,no stutter was noticed. Did you think it's make any sense?

Comment: yup, will you try to use CMTimeMaxScale at this line?  
`let frameTime = CMTime(seconds: frameDuration, preferredTimescale: CMTimeMaxTimeScale` it's in your `for loop`

Comment: Unfortunately , `CMTimeMaxTimeScale ` coudn't help the situation. 
But I notice that when I _export_ the `AVAsset` and play it with QuickTime on my Mac , it runs smoothly. 
The same _exported video_  fails to run smoothly in the _Photos_ app of the simulator. I can't understand what's wrong.